# Protractor: how to iterate and compare values got using repeater from application and from scenario tables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm getting the list of actual values from application using repeater function and expected values from scenario data table. How can I **store and compare actual values** with the expected values?

Scenario: 
Scenario: As a user, i should be able to login to the application and view the list of users and registration date
  Given I login to the application with username "abcd" and password "passwOrd123"
  When I open the view member registration
  Then the following users and registration date must be listed:
  |userName|registrationDate|
  |user1|05/30/2010  |
  |user2|06/11/2009  |

Below is the implementation code i wrote for then step:

```js
this.Then(/^Then the following users and registration date must be listed:$/, function (table) {

        var data = table.hashes();

        element.all(by.repeater('members in member list')).then(function(member) {

            for (i=0;i<member.length;i++) {
                member[i].element(by.binding('app.memberName')).getText().then(function (actualMemberName) {
                    console.log("Member Name: " + actualMemberName);
                });

                member[i].element(by.binding("app.reg.date | jsonDate:'MM/dd/yyyy'")).getText().then(function (actualRegDate) {
                    console.log("Actual Registration Date: " + actualRegDate);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

List of users returned by 'members in member' list will not be in the same order all the time.

Comment: Use `expect`. Follow this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602416/how-to-compare-actual-and-expected-values-in-angular-js-protractor

Answer (score 1):

Which Framework are you using? If you are using Jasmine framework then you can add **expect** statements inside your **for** loop to verify actual and expected values like this snippet -

```
expect(actual_value).toEqual(expected_value);
```

If you  are not using any frameworks then you can try verifying the values using plain javascript like this snippet -

```
if(actual_value === expected_value)
    //do something
else
    //print error
```

OR

```
if(actual_value.localeCompare(expected_value) == 0)
    //do something
else
    //print error
```

Both functions work the same way.

To store the list of users from repeater function, check out the [MAP function](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map)
 available in protractor. It stores the data from **element.all()** function serially in an array. You can later use that array to check with the table. Here's an example -

```
element.all('selector here').map(function(ele){
    return ele.getText().then(function(arrayText){
            return arrayText;
        });
    }).then(function(arrayText){
            //arrayText is an array with list of elements from repeater function
            //Use the arrayText and compare it to your table
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get a list of users using repeater function. I don't know how to store them and compare with the data table i get from the scenario.

Comment: Updated with the map function above which can help you store the values from repeater function.